# SQL Select syntax error in three tables

Tags: sql, select, syntax-error

```
SELECT Surname
FROM Worker
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT *
FROM Project, Works_at
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT *
FROM Works_at
WHERE Works_at.WorkerId =Worker.Id
AND Works_at.PNum = Project.PNumber
)
);
```

or

```
SELECT Surname
FROM Worker
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM Works_at
WHERE Id = WorkerId
);
```

When I run the queries, It says that there is a syntax error  near "SELECT"
What can go wrong?
First one selects the workers works in all Projects.
And the second one selects the worker doesn't work in any Project.
Thanks in advance

Tables are

> Worker = {Name, Surname, Id, Salary, DptNum}
>
> Department = {DptName, DptNumber}
>
> Works_at = {WorkerId, PNum, Hours}
>
> Project={PName, PNumber, DptNum} and
>
> Works_at(WorkerId) → Worker(Id)
>
> Works_at(PNum) → Projekt(PNumber)
>
> Project(DptNum) → Department(DptNumber)
>
> Worker(DptNum) → Department(DptNumber)

Comment: What select is the error referring to?

Comment: Error in not working in any projects are solved.The first code I wrote at the top for the workers works at all projects I can't solve

Comment: Select error referring to Surname at top at the first code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOT IN subselects are terrible for performance.  You are better to hit with a LEFT-JOIN and testing for NULL (ie: doesn't have a match)

```
SELECT 
      W.Surname
   FROM 
      Worker W
         LEFT JOIN Works_At WA
            on W.ID = WA.WorkerID
            LEFT JOIN Project P
               on WA.PNum = P.PNumber
   WHERE
      P.PNumber IS NULL
```

This should give you a list of people who are Not associated with a project.  That is based on there being a possibility of a Works At location, but no project being assigned.  If there would be no record in the works at table, then it would even be simpler with

```
SELECT 
      W.Surname
   FROM 
      Worker W
         LEFT JOIN Works_At WA
            on W.ID = WA.WorkerID
   WHERE
      WA.WorkerID IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response. The first one works now. But the second one I can't figure it out selecting the workers works at all projects

Comment: I don't understand your comment without seeing some sample data of Worker, WorksAt and Projects for what you do/dont want.  The second query gets all people who are not associated with ANY "Works_At" records (and thus would never have any corresponding project either).

Answer (score 1):

You can not access Works_at.PNum = Project.PNumber as project table is not available to that subquery.